# MySQL, using field value as alias

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to design a stored procedure that will join two tables `credentials`and `contact` by `user_id`. In the expected result set, `contact`provides values from two fields (`contact_type`and `address`) where `contact.contact_type` values are used as field name and `contact.address`values are used as values. Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure()
BEGIN
start transaction;
set @v = null;
select
    credentials.*,
    concat('case when credentials.user_id = contact.user_id then contact.address end as ',contact.contact_type)
from credentials left join contact on credentials.user_id = contact.user_id
where credentials.user_id not in ('4510180001', '3870180002') into @v;

prepare stmt from @v;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
commit;
END
```

When I execute this code, I get the error: `Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

When I change the scenario as following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `allUser`()
BEGIN
start transaction;
set @v = null;
select concat('select
    credentials.*,
    case when credentials.user_id = contact.user_id then contact.address end as ',contact.contact_type)
from credentials left join contact on credentials.user_id = contact.user_id
where credentials.user_id not in ('4510180001', '3870180002') into @v;

prepare stmt from @v;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
commit;
END
```

I get the error: `Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row`

I am looking for a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, you are getting an error because you need to `select...into` the same number of variables that you have COLUMNS. So:

```
select
credentials.*,
concat('case when credentials.user_id = contact.user_id then contact.address end as ',contact.contact_type)

from credentials left join contact on credentials.user_id = contact.user_id
where credentials.user_id not in ('4510180001', '3870180002') into @v,@w,@x,@y;
```

.. and so on. You need a variable for every column that query returns.

The second part is similar, except you are trying to put multiple ROWS into the variable. Variables can only hold one value/row at a time. You would need to add a LIMIT 1 clause to the end of the query.

I'm guessing neither of these answers may be helpful, because you trying to prepare a statement. In that case, the ENTIRE query needs to be wrapped with concat, and then put into the variable. Like so:

```
select concat('select credentials.*,
case when credentials.user_id = contact.user_id then contact.address end as contact.contact_type
from credentials left join contact on credentials.user_id = contact.user_id
where credentials.user_id not in ('4510180001', '3870180002')) into @v;
```